# Right way to create Yes/No boolean fields

Tags: 7, entities

I want to add fields in my node which will contain boolean values only : Yes/No. Selecting boolean as field type will cause the field to show up as single check box and in the node edit form I've difficulty in locating boolean type field.

Currently I'm using List(Text) and giving values as 1|Yes & 0|No.

What is the right way to use boolean values?

Comment: look in to this https://drupal.org/project/boolean

Comment: but very less people using it ..

Comment: It depends on user needs

Comment: I want to look for solution from core fields only initially. If it does not work out then only I should go for user modules.

Comment: _"Selecting boolean as field type will cause the field to show up as single check box"_ Yep, that's exactly what should happen. What problem is that causing you exactly, and what are you trying to achieve? If you're looking for a boolean field, that's what Drupal core provides. If you need a more advanced pseudo-boolean field (i.e. the 'Yes/No' select box that you mention) then you're already doing it the correct way by using a text list field.

Comment: Clive can you pl. place the text in answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

As follows:

- Field type: **List (integer)** & Widget: **Check boxes/radio buttons**
- Values: **1|Yes**
- Number of values: **unlimited**

See [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/1387834)

Answer (score 0):

I would create:

1. **List (Text)** with the **Check boxes/radio buttons** widget
2. Make two options: **1|Yes** and **2|No**
3. Number of values: **1**
4. **Most importantly**: put the field on Required. This way you get radio buttons where only one option can and must be selected.